# Make sure AJAX request is complete before firing the route in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

We have a horrible asynchronous situation whereas, we need certain AJAX requests to complete before the Router fires it's routes.

How can I make sure that certain AJAX requests have fired before Backbone Router fires any route?

More of a conceptual question I know, but any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@nikoshr is correct.

Another approach could be prevent automatic routing on click event and then trigger the `route` event manually when the ajax responses are done.

```
$.when(xhr1, xhr2).then(function () { 
   router.trigger("route", "route-name", any_args);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Routes will fire only when [`Backbone.history.start`](http://backbonejs.org/#History-start) is called :

> **start** *Backbone.history.start([options])*
>   When all of your Routers have been created, and all of the routes are set up properly, call Backbone.history.start() to begin monitoring hashchange events, and dispatching routes.

This means that you can achieve what you want by waiting for your Ajax requests to complete before making this call.

Assuming you use jQuery>=1.5 as your $ of choice and that your Ajax requests are model fetches, you could use the [Deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) returned by `model.fetch` to synchronize your actions:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'index'
    },

    index: function() {
        console.log('route')
    }
});

var M = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/echo/json/?delay=1'
});

var r = new Router();
var m1 = new M();
var m2 = new M();

var xhr1 = m1.fetch(),
    xhr2 = m2.fetch();

$.when(xhr1, xhr2).then(function() {
    console.log('requests');
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

And a Fiddle to play with http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/fnsqU/